# How does ion-toggle work

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

The [Ionic 2 Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toggle/Toggle/) doesn't really explain on how to use `ion-toggle`. I would like to take the values from the `On` Checkbox/Toggle to next page/state.

Please help in understanding.

**TypeScript**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Apis } from '../../app/apis';
import { BookingConfirmationPage } from '../booking-confirmation/booking-confirmation';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-booking-enhancement',
  templateUrl: 'booking-enhancement.html',
  providers: [Apis]
})
export class BookingEnhancementPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public Apis: Apis ) {

  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let item of extra" class="row-extra">
        <ion-col width-10>
            <ion-toggle class="switcher display-block" color="secondary"></ion-toggle>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-67 class="description">{{ item.description }}</ion-col>
        <ion-col width-23 style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="rate text-center display-block">${{ item.rate }}</div>
            <div class="qty text-center display-block"><input type="number" class="text-center"/></div>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-col width-100 class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="continue" (click)="ContinueBookingConfirmation()">Continue</button></ion-col>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: you need to add a ngmodel on the toggle and pass it with the navCtrl `this.navCtrl.push(PAGE,ngmodal);`